# Dynamic Element Height Jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, height

So basically I want my sidebar to be the same height as my main content area... This is the very simple code i wrote out and im just not sure why its not working, "px" doesnt seem to be appending to the string...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $height = $("div#content").height();
var $sidebar = $height + "px";

$("div#sidebar").css("height","$sidebar");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#sidebar").css("height","$sidebar");
```

should be

```
$("div#sidebar").css("height",$sidebar)
```

OR simple

```
 $("div#sidebar").height($("#content").height())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sidebar").height($("#content").height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this wrong.

```
$("div#sidebar").css("height","$sidebar");

$("div#sidebar").css("height",$sidebar);
```

Additionally to include the margin and padding you should pass argurment true to height
like

```
$("div#content").height(true);
```